# How do I store data from a for-loop into an array?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

Here I have this where import data as arrays then, operates on those arrays with a function

```
import numpy as np

n1 = an array of 999 numbers
mass1= an array of 999 numbers
x1= an array of 999 numbers
y1=an array of 999 numbers
z1=an array of 999 numbers
dt=.0001
npoints=len(n1)
xn=0
step=1

for timedt in xrange(0,npoints-1):
     step=step


     for l in xrange(0,npoints-1):
         xn=xn

         f=x1,y1,z1[xn]+x1,y1,z1[step]

     xn=xn+1
     step=step+1

     print f
```

However, when I print out f, I just get a huge list set of numbers in the format

```
.....
-9.622302989262075e-07
0.00016890654402323984
2.261014843829707e-05
-0.00011706036947314393
-7.791712660429376e-05
1.0156155973842854e-05
0.00019244252361596046
-0.00019202953520118445
0.04082168851673397
-0.001675463103312094
-1.4584179607758451e-05
3.788355464183264
3.99516377369456e-05
```

But I want to make these numbers be one array. In additon if I print f outside of that loop, I only get the last number. 
    3.99516377369456e-05

But I want to be able to print all of them outside of the loop as an array.

```
np.asarray
```

doesn't work.

Comment: What shape and dtype do you want?  Is `n1` really an 'array' (as in `numpy.ndarray`), or just a sloppy way of saying `list`?

Comment: n1 is really an array. I don't think I care what shape I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would possibly be:

```
f_array = []
for ...:
    ...
    for ...:
        f = ...
    f_array.append(f)

f_array = np.array(f_array)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I tried doing something similar, but I didn't add the last line.